# MSSQL varchar размер

Tags: sql-server, sql

Доброго времени суток, ув. пользователи портала ХэшКод.

Меня интересует довольно простой и в то же время важный вопрос. СУБД Microsoft SQL Server поддерживает тип данных varchar, что представляет строку символов. Вопрос: размер данных в varchar зависит от максимальной длины?

Есть если создать две переменных:

1. A varchar(1024)='HASHCODE';
2. B varchar(32)='HASHCODE'.

Их размер будет одинаковым или разным?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению под рукой нет работающего SQL-сервера, чтобы проверить пример из [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) , но это должно быть то, что вам нужно. Вроде ничего сложного:

```
SELECT length = DATALENGTH(A), A
FROM DB.YourTable
```

и

```
SELECT length = DATALENGTH(B), B
FROM DB.YourTable
```

Comment: Благодарю. Как видим, размер от макс. длины не зависит.

    DECLARE @A varchar(1024)  = 'HASHCODE'
    DECLARE @B varchar(32)  = 'HASHCODE'
    
    SELECT DATALENGTH(@A) as len_a
    -- out: 8
    SELECT DATALENGTH(@B) as len_b
    -- out: 8

Comment: Самому интересно стало :)

Comment: Круть! Раньше не знал про функцию "DATALENGTH". Теперь всегда буду юзать!

    DECLARE @C char(1024) = 'HASHCODE'
    SELECT DATALENGTH(@C) as len_c
    -- out: 8

Comment: учитывайте, что datalength возвращает длину в байтах, а в строках ntext, nchar и nvarchar каждый символ занимает два байта.

Answer (score 4):

Varchar - указывается максимальный размер. Место в памяти занимается по размеру фактических данных.

Char - указывается точный размер. Если данные занимают меньше места, то они дополняются пробелами справа до указанного размера.